# Autocomplete Textbox using web api

Tags: c#, jquery, json

I am try to create a autocomplete textbox using web api. I have checked a lot of websites but still I am not understand anything.
my web api contains data in format
"[{\"sl_no\":\"305\"},{\"sl_no\":\"305\"},{\"sl_no\":\"3056\"},{\"sl_no\":\"3057\"},{\"sl_no\":\"3305\"}]"

i want autocomplete textbox on entering text for eg. text=305 then it should give rest of the options i.e. 3056,3057,3305

i am trying to do it with jquery autocomplete widget

Comment: There are lots of jquery autocomplete tutorials, here's one for you. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/mvc4-jquery-autocomplete-textbox-using-web-api/

Comment: There are lots of snippets, examples e docs in the [widget's page](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). If you *not understand anything* you should try javascript fundamentals first.

Comment: Thank you for comments and motivation, really appreciated. I was looking for direct code without trying much,. Right now I got a working example with html datalist. I am going through jquery bsics to understand it better.
Once again Thank You:-)

Answer (score 0):

To implement Google Places Autocomplete Text Box you firstly need an API key which can be obtained on the Google API website. All you need to do is sign up for one by filling in your required personal information. Once you have an API Key all you need to do is go under the API library and Enable the places API. Once that is done Copy and paste the following code into the view of your Asp.Net MVC application...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&Key=YOURAPIKEY"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {  
            var options = {  
                types: ['(cities)'],  
                componentRestrictions: { country: "sa" }  
            };  

            var input = document.getElementById('Address');  
            var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);  


        });  
</script>
```

once you have copied and pasted this code, fill in your API Key in the required place where its states (Key=YOURAPIKEY). once this is done you can now run your application and it should come up like this...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ctx.png)